# Add Primary Key constraint to partitions of a table in Postgres 13

Tags: postgresql, constraints, primary-key

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I need to convert an existing non-partitioned table to a partitioned table. Since you can't alter an existing table to be partitioned, I created a new partitioned table. According to the PostgreSQL documentation, you can't add constraints to a partitioned table. Constraints must be added to partitions. When I try to add Primary Key constraints to the partitions, I get an error. Can you suggest a way to add constraints to this partition?

`purchase_history_within_10_months` is the new partition name.

SQL query:

> ALTER TABLE ONLY purchase_history_within_10_months
> ADD CONSTRAINT purchase_history_pkey PRIMARY KEY (transactionid);

Error Statement:

> ERROR:  relation "purchase_history_pkey" already exists
>
> SQL state: 42P07

According to the error message, there is an existing constraint with the same name for this partition.

I have checked the existing constraints for this partition.

SQL query:

> appxxxx=# SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE table_name = 'purchase_history_within_10_months';
> constraint_name     | constraint_type |            table_name
> ------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------
> 2200_30127_1_not_null  | CHECK           | purchase_history_within_10_months
> 2200_30127_14_not_null | CHECK           | purchase_history_within_10_months
> 2200_30127_16_not_null | CHECK           | purchase_history_within_10_months
> 2200_30127_36_not_null | CHECK           | purchase_history_within_10_months
> (4 rows)
>
> appxxxx=#
> appxxxx=#

According to this, there is no constraint with the same name on this partition. So, what is causing this issue?

Comment: See also [At what level do Postgres index names need to be unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306539/at-what-level-do-postgres-index-names-need-to-be-unique)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to this, there is no constraint with the same name on this partition. So, what is causing this issue?

In Postgres constraint names need to be unique within the schema, not just within the table. So somewhere in you schema there is already another constraint by that name.

I recommend following the automatic nameing scheme and prefixing each constraint name by the table name, so in your case the constraint would be named `purchase_history_within_10_months_pkey`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Although the new table does not have a constraint with the same name, the old table does. I cannot change the name of this constraint. Therefore, I have to use the same name. The old table can be deleted after the data is copied to the new table. If we try this method, we will first copy the data from the old table, delete the old table, and then alter the new table and add the constraint with the same name. My question is, if we do this, will the constraint apply to the data that we already copied? Because we copied the data before adding the constraint.

Comment: Yes, a newly added constraint generally also applies to already existing data. I would however recommend creating the constraint with a temporary name before inserting the data and renaming it afterwards to the desired name. See [Constraint name update in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971786/constraint-name-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: This way, it works. I alter existing constraint name and create new constraint before copying data to table.